# pycharm 'module' has no attribute

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been using pycharm for a little while and all working fine, then this morning I started it up and went to run some python code and got the message 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'

I ran the code in another IDE (spyder) and it works fine,I haven't changed any settings in pycharm that I know of, anyone have any ideas what could be causing this issue?

my code:

```
def fac(num,yi):
    import random
    x = [[0,0]]
    if num > 0.1:
        x.append([num,yi])
        x.extend(fac(num/2,yi+0.1*random.randrange(-10,10,1)))

    return(x)


print(fac(10, 0))
```

Comment: It works fine in my pycharm. You should try to open python console tab and type `import random`, `random.randrange(-10,10,1)` to see if it still works

Comment: Do you have any python modules or packages named 'random'? These could be imported accidentally rather than the system library. One way you can check definitively is to output random.__file__ from code where you're seeing the issue.

Comment: Check the `Settings` and make sure that you use the interpreter you want to use. To me it sounds like PyCharm is pointing to a different interpreter....

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, and confirmed that the code was correct by running it in IDLE. Restarting PyCharm fixed it for me; it now runs fine.